# Why does Pycharm debugger always stop at entry point?

Tags: debugging, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm Edu 4.0.2 in debugging mode.
It invariably stops on the first line of the script being run, even though I have not set a break point there.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know why?
Thanks